# Create a dynamic goback

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm aware of the `onclick="javascript: history.go(-1)"`, but that's wrong on a dynamic forum, if a user for example creates a new thread, then it updates and his history is different. How to create a dynamic "Go back" button? I'm coding in asp mvc.

I'm using this to go to my "post" page dynamic:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Thread.Title, "Post", "Threads", new { @id = Thread.Id }, new { @class = "CategoryTitles" })
```

But i'm not sure how i can reverce it, some one that know how i should do it reverce?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use following code for redirecting to previous URL in asp.net MVC.

//View code
@Html.ActionLink(Thread.Title, "MyNextAction", "Threads", new { @id = Thread.Id }, new { @class = "CategoryTitles" })

// Controller code
public ActionResult MyNextAction()
{
    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What using are you using? Because i'm getting this error: http://prntscr.com/9et72x

Comment: Make sure you have included following name spaces.

    using System;

    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.Mvc;